# How to use over function in piggybank

Tags: apache-pig, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I'm new to Apache pig and cannot figure out what goes wrong for the cumulative calculation using Over function of piggybank. I would like the cumulative salary over each period given the same business and location for the following data:

```
business|location|period|salary
--------+--------+------+-------
100     |  East  |   1  |  100
100     |  East  |   1  |  55
100     |  East  |   2  |  100
100     |  East  |   3  |  150
100     |  West  |   1  |  150
100     |  West  |   2  |  200
100     |  West  |   3  |  250
200     |  East  |   1  |  50
200     |  East  |   2  |  50
200     |  East  |   3  |  50
200     |  West  |   1  |  80
200     |  West  |   2  |  100
200     |  West  |   3  |  120
```

The result I'm looking for is:

```
business|location|period|cumulative salary
--------+--------+------+---------------
  100   |  East  |  1   |    155
  100   |  East  |  2   |    255
  100   |  East  |  3   |    405
  100   |  West  |  1   |    150
  100   |  West  |  2   |    350
  100   |  West  |  3   |    600
  200   |  East  |  1   |    50
  200   |  East  |  2   |    100
  200   |  East  |  3   |    150
  200   |  West  |  1   |    80
  200   |  West  |  2   |    180
  200   |  West  |  3   |    300
```

According to this Over doc, I should be able to do it by

```
REGISTER /opt/mapr/pig/pig-0.12/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar;
A = LOAD '/user/sliang/pig/testData' USING PigStorage(',') as (business:long, location:chararray, period:long, salary:long);
B = group A by (business, location);
C = foreach B {
    C1 = order A by period;
    generate flatten(Stitch(C1, Over(C1.salary, 'sum(long)')));
};
D = foreach C generate business, location, period, $9;
```

But I got error start at C:

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve Stitch using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

I googled but there is not much info regarding this... I also checked the jar with other piggybank function and it works, so I guess it's not because piggybank is not correctly registered. I'm using pig 0.12 version.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use full package path of `Stitch` and Over `command`.

ie, replace `Stitch` with `org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Stitch`and
          `Over` with `org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Over`

if you want to avoid the above lengthy package name in your pig script then define your own macro something like this and use it in your pig script.

```
DEFINE MYOVER org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Over;  

DEFINE MYSTITCH org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Stitch;
```

**Updated Pigscript:**

```
A =  LOAD '/user/sliang/pig/testData' USING PigStorage(',') as (business:long, location:chararray, period:long, salary:long);
B = group A by (business, location);
C = foreach B {
    C1 = order A by period;
    generate flatten(org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Stitch(C1, org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.Over(C1.salary, 'sum(long)')));
};
D = foreach C generate business, location, period, $4;

E = RANK D;
F = GROUP E BY (stitched::business,stitched::location,stitched::period);
G = FOREACH F {
                 sortRankByDesc = ORDER E BY rank_D DESC;
                 topRank = LIMIT sortRankByDesc 1;
                 GENERATE FLATTEN(topRank);
              }
H = FOREACH G GENERATE $1 AS business,$2 AS location,$3 AS period,$4 AS salary;
DUMP H;
```

**Output**

```
(100,East,1,155)
(100,East,2,255)
(100,East,3,405)
(100,West,1,150)
(100,West,2,350)
(100,West,3,600)
(200,East,1,50)
(200,East,2,100)
(200,East,3,150)
(200,West,1,80)
(200,West,2,180)
(200,West,3,300)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! A follow up question: how to get the cumulative sum for unique (business,location,period)? i.e. How to get only (100,East,1,155) without (100,East,1,100)?